# Structural pattern matching with unions

Tags: python

I want to test if a variable is of any type defined in a `typing.Union`.

In a seperate file, let's call it typing_utils.py, I have defined a union as

```
from typing import Union

my_union = Union[my_type_1, my_type_2, ..., my_type_n]
```

Now, in a different file, I want to check if a variable is of any of the types contained in `my_union`. How would I go about this?

The naive approach would be something like

```
import typing_utils

var = my_type_1(...)

match var:
    case typing_utils.my_union:  # Notice that this is a "dotted" variable, so it isn't bound anew.
        print("Detected a type within my_union.")
```

but this never detects the type correctly. I suspect this has something to do with the syntax that, at least grammatically, requires what resembles a call to the constructor of the class to test against, i.e. `case my_type_1()` instead of `case my_type_1`.

Is there any way I can solve this programmatically without having to manually type out all n types again? Of course, `isinstance(var, my_union)` also works, but later cases get a bit more complicated so this seems to me like a perfect example of where to use structural pattern matching over the old `if isinstance(...)/elif isinstance(...) and .../...` waterfall.